# ¿como verificar si el user ya existe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

en mi backend no se estan creando duplicados pero en la parte del front en la ruta `/signup` si estoy pudiendo registrarme muchas veces con un usuario que ya existe, como puedo limitar esto y tal vez lanzar un mensaje que diga que ese email ya fue usado.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { API } from '../config';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Signup = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        error: "",
        success: false
    });
    const { name, email, password, error, success } = values;

    const handleChange = name => event => {
        setValues({ ...values, error: false, [name]: event.target.value });
    }

    const signup = user => {
        return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    const clickSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setValues({ ...values, error: false });

        signup({ name, email, password })
        .then(data => {
            if(data.error) {
                setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, success: false });
            } else {
                setValues({ ...values, name: "", email: "", password: "", error: "", success: true });
            }
        });
    }

    const showError = () => {
        return (
            <div className="alert alert-danger" style={{ display: error ? "" : "none" }}>
            { error }
            </div>
        );
    }

    const showSuccess = () => {
        return (
            <div className="alert alert-info" style={{ display: success ? "" : "none" }}>
            A new account was created, please <Link to="/signin">signin</Link>.
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (  
        <div className="register-background">
        <div className="container">
            { showSuccess() }
            { showError() }
        <div className="box-header text-center">
            <p>Signup</p>
        </div>
        <form className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input onChange={handleChange("name")} type="text" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="Enter your name." 
                    value={name} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input onChange={handleChange("email")} type="email" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="Enter your email."
                    value={email} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input onChange={handleChange("password")} type="password" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="enter your password."
                    value={password} />
                </div>
                <button onClick={clickSubmit} className="btn btn-block btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Signup;
```

Comment: ¿Con qué lenguaje haces el servicio? PHP?

Comment: con Node, Express pero no me crea duplicados porque mi modelo tiene la propiedad unique en email, pero me estoy pudiendo registrar varias veces.

Comment: Vale, te dejo como un ejemplo de lo que puedes hacer y tú lo acomodas, ya que el lenguaje no lo he manejado

Comment: dale gracias voy a mirar el ejemplo :)

Comment: y el ejemplo? @DaxTter77

Comment: Dame un segundo

Comment: ah disculpame, si te espero.

Comment: Listo, revisalo y me dices lo que no entiendas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer una consulta antes de mandar los datos a registrar del usuario, por ejemplo, llenas el formulario, le da a enviar, y el sistema en vez de mandarlo directamente a registrar hace una consulta primero y sí no hay registros de esa misma persona, entonces sí manda a registrar, por ejemplo, puedes hacer la consulta así

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE email = $email";
```

Haces que sí la consulta retorna vacía, la variable donde guardes el resultado tome un valor `null`, de lo contrario que tome la consulta, y retornas el valor y en `react` lo recibes y haces algo así

```
fetch(`${API}/select_users`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((respuesta){
           if(respuesta != null){
              console.log("no existe el usuario");
           }else{console.log("Ya existe el usuario")}
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Espero que te sirva y lo puedas entender, ya que hace rato no tocaba `react`